# single TRUE/FALSE for entire data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R as: `data.frame(A=0.5,B=18,C=0)`. My goal is to check if the data frame has `NA` or not. when I run `is.na(data.frame(A=0.5,B=18,C=0))`, the output gives give me TRUE/FALSE for each of the columns.

```
         A     B     C
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Given the fact that my result will have either `NA` for all columns or numeric values for all columns, is there a way to perform something like `is.na()` for the data frame and a get an output as a single TRUE or FALSE, instead of column wise TRUE or FALSE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `anyNA` like this:

```r
anyNA(data.frame(A=0.5,B=18,C=0))
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could also just append `any` to your current code:

```
any(is.na(data.frame(A=0.5,B=18,C=0)))
# [1] FALSE
```